# HTML+CSS Text Container Design

Tags: html, css, textbox, webkit

So here's the website that has the container that I want to emulate: [container](http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/uscrollbar/demo/)

Here's the textbox specifically:
[image: Website Container]

Here's what mine looks like:
[image: My container]

They gave their css file and I looked at their html source code. I got the part in the html and css that pertains to the demo text and style. Here's all the code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJqvG/)

I'm pretty new to web programming, just a couple weeks in. And the css for the demo text looks daunting. I'm trying figure out how mine is different. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to fix my container to look like theirs? Thanks

Comment: What is your browser? I see no problem with fiddle

Comment: @FAngel Chrome but I don't think it's a problem with the browser because I'm viewing the original perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/dain/XJqvG/6/

The main problems were:

- you haven't included the required JavaScript and CSS files, this
  custom scrollbar requires the libraries as explained at the top of the article
- you have to set a fixed height on the sample element

For some reason it still doesn't want to scroll with the touchpad, but that might just be something with JSFiddle.

Comment: what part of that only affects the textbox? Because using the entire css file affects other parts of the page, such as the background, that I don't want it to affect.

Comment: try to inspect the element in Chrome / Firefox and you should be able to see what CSS rules apply on it