# HTML + CSS Text container adjustment

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins, textbox

I'm trying to get emulate [this](http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/uscrollbar/demo/) textbox container. But the thing is I am trying to adjust the height of the header, this part:
[image: Container]

They provide all the files (html, css, js) of that page [here](http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/uscrollbar/)

I've been searching through the documentation.css file for a while now to figure out where it is I can adjust the height of that box but I have been unsuccessful so far. This is what mine looks like:
[image: my container]

As you can see mine looks almost exactly the same just the height of that box is too big. I'm fairly new to web programming so i might not be looking for the right thing in the right place so I'm hoping some more experienced eyes can figure it out.

Thanks for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML+CSS Text Container Design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521929/htmlcss-text-container-design)

Comment: @j08691 no that was to get it working in the first place. I got it working, now I just need to figure out how to make this one adjustment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css is minified, what makes it a little more complex for beginers...

But if you search for `.main-content>header` in the file `documentation.css` you will notice it's setting up a padding.

The demo in the link you posted has:

```
padding:15px 30px;
```

In your code the first number is probably higher than 15, setting up a higher top/bottom padding. Just adjust it as you will.

Comment: Ah, thank you. One more thing, is it normal to write convoluted code like this. Why do they have so many nested divs/sections??

Comment: It seems ok. Have you already studied about the semantics of HTML5? I recomend you take a look at this book: [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/).

The div is just a delimiter, with no semantic value. In the demo makup they have a main `<div>` for the component, inside it a `<header>` and a `<section>`. Inside the `<section>` another `<div>` for the contents.